# Storing IP with INET_ATON - signed or unsigned integer?

Tags: php, mysql, ip, unsigned, signed

Is it necessary to use an **unsigned** integer column to store an IP(v4) address (that has been converted with `INET_ATON`) in MySQL?

I spontaneous would think that it really does NOT matter, since no matter how the field is defined, the same data will be used to convert it back with `INET_NTOA`.
So the only difference would be, that in one case you see a negative number in your db while with unsigned you would see a (totally) different positive number, while the actual data is the same in both cases, just representation differs through field definition, is that correct?

Comment: P.S.  When asking for help, it usually isn't smart to put "stipulations".  Just take what you need from what is offered.  It probably took you more to write those out than it would have to just sort through comments.

Comment: @Devon: Removed the "pleas" ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [docs on INET_ATON()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton):

> To store values generated by INET_ATON(), use an INT UNSIGNED column
>   rather than INT, which is signed. If you use a signed column, values
>   corresponding to IP addresses for which the first octet is greater
>   than 127 cannot be stored correctly. See [Section 11.2.6, “Out-of-Range
>   and Overflow Handling](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/out-of-range-and-overflow.html).

Why not just use an unsigned to guarantee compatibility?  What are the downsides to using unsigned in your scenario that would make you question this?

Comment: +1 Thx for the quote! It was actually my question, if an IP address with its first octed greater than 127 would therefore be stored as a negative number, but work as well. Thx for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:** `USIGNED` is necessary, if you want to store an IP with it's first octet greater than 127!

From the MySQL Docs about [11.2.6 Out-of-Range and Overflow Handling](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/out-of-range-and-overflow.html):

> - If strict SQL mode is enabled, MySQL rejects the out-of-range value with an error, and the insert fails, in accordance with the SQL standard.
> - If no restrictive modes are enabled, MySQL clips the value to the appropriate endpoint of the range and stores the resulting value instead.

So what happens if you try to store an IP address greater than 127.255.255.255 in a `SIGNED INTEGER` field, depends on wether restrictive modes are enabled or not, but in either case it does **NOT** work as you would want it to.

#### Even if no restrictive modes are enabled ...

> When an out-of-range value is assigned to an integer column, MySQL stores the value representing the corresponding endpoint of the column data type range. If you store 256 into a `TINYINT` or `TINYINT UNSIGNED` column, MySQL stores 127 or 255, respectively.